# Node.js webserver becoming unresponsive under intensive calculation cycles

Tags: node.js, express

The below Node.js code will not allow any incoming webserver requests until the `calculate()` finished computing. Shouldn't event loop pause this function somehow periodically to see if there isn't anything incoming on the network stack? How can I prevent such situations happening within my node.js codebase? That is, perform expensive calculations, yet still ensure responsiveness of the network endpoints?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

function calculate() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let payload = [];
    let msgArr = [];
    let max = 10000;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        payload.push(rand);
    }
    let msg = {};
    msg.payload = payload;
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        let msgCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg));
        msgArr.push(msgCopy);
    }
    
    let msgLen = msgArr.length;
    while (msgLen--) {
      msgArr[msgLen].payload = msgArr[msgLen].payload.sort();
      console.log("Remaining: " + msgLen);
    }
    res();
  });
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
  calculate();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript always finishes synchronous code before taking new work from the event loop. There are two ways around this:

### Partitioning

To process incoming requests, stop the `calculate()` method and put the remaining work itself on the event loop, for example with `setTimeout` and `async`:

```js
function yieldControlToEventLoop() {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 0));
}

async function calculate() {
  // ...
  let max = 10000;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    payload.push(rand);
    // Interrupt every 1000 iterations, change this value as appropriate
    if (i % 1000 === 0) {
      await yieldControlToEventLoop();
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

When `await yieldControlToEventLoop()` is executed, it creates a task to continue the work of the `calculate()` and places that task at the end of the event loop - meaning that other events are processed first.

### Offloading

If you receive too many requests, or the `calculate()` method takes too much time, offloading the work to a different thread may be the better option. This is more complicated, but allows you to take advantage of multiple CPU cores and run long calculations without conflicting with the main thread.

The [Worker threads documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) would be a good starting point for this.

Further reading: [Complex calculations without blocking the Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop#complex-calculations-without-blocking-the-event-loop)